# Compare two proportions with a Bayesian analysis

Tags: r, proportion, fishers-exact-test, z-test, bayes-factors

I'm conducting an experiment in which participants receive either an object A or an object B. Next, we ask participants if they want to trade their objects with the alternative object (i.e., object B for participants receiving object A, and Object A for participants receiving object B). I want to compare the proportion or frequency of participants that refuse to trade A with B, with the proportion or frequency of participants that accept to trade B with A.

Is it possible to conduct such an analysis? Especially, a Bayesian analysis?

Such an analysis looks like an A/B test, except that I want to compare non-occurrence in group A with occurrence in group B.

Thanks

Comment: Should be possible.  Just code the non-acceptance as the "1" and acceptance as the "0" and use ... whatever method you like

Comment: Do you mean I code Refusing as 1 for group A and Acceptance as 1 for group B?